# What is the difference between access viewer and security editor in sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

Any changes made in access viewer gets reflected  automatically in security editor and vice versa in sitecore.

Answer (score 8):

The functionality really overlaps a bit. You may configure security using either of them, but depending on the scenario it might be convenient or not.

The main purpose of the Security Editor is (not a surprise) to edit the security settings. When you're in the SE, *every click* in the highlighted area alters item security:

[image]

That might be useful when you need to set numerous access rights and you know for sure that it needs to be set exactly like that (e.g. when you're denying access to a set of items).

From the other side, SE does not show you the full picture. It deals with the *explicitly configured* access rights. Sitecore allows to configure security for *numerous* accounts, [security settings can be inherited](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/access_rights/the_inheritance_access_right), there might be [conflicting access rights settings](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/access_rights/assigning_access_rights).

That is where Access Viewer shines. It shows *all the settings* that impact the final access result for the particular user and item (including inheritance and impact of any other accounts):

[image]

Comment: Adding to the above ans, Access viewer is read only and hence you cannot edit any settings over there.You can only view the cumulative security settings while in SE you can edit.

Answer (score 0):

Security Editor is the application within Sitecore backend which give the ability to tune access for appropriate roles/users.
Access Viewer is application too, but it is used to show the result of security settings.